# Why can't I get features to show up when I could using openlayers-angular-directive?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Trying to get up and going with a fairly simple map. I was using the openlayers-angular-directive, and this same http request and layer setup was working (the geojson features were displaying as red vectors on a layer above the stamen layer). Now, I'm deciding I want a "vanilla" openlayers setup (see below), and I can only get the stamen layer to show up. What could I be missing?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.1/ol-debug.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.14.0/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.1/ol-debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="olMap"></div>
    <script>
      let olMap = document.getElementById('olMap');

      let parcelVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

      let map = new ol.Map({
        target: olMap,
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
              layer: 'toner'
            })
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: parcelVectorSource,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'white',
                width: 3,
              }),
            }),
          }),
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-111.6597963, 40.2119769]),
          zoom: 16,
        })
      });

      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/2/parcels/')
        .then(result => updateMap(result.data));

      function updateMap (geojsonObj) {
        let geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        let features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(geojsonObj);
        parcelVectorSource.addFeatures(features);
      }
    </script>
  </body></html>
```

Comment: I can just tell that the OpenLayers part is working fine, as tested here with a sample geoJSON: https://jsfiddle.net/h92bgozg/.   You might want to check your request again, unfortunately I am not familiar with the axios library, so I can't help you there.

Comment: As I said, the request is the same as the example I have working. And I log out the response and the data is valid geojson format as delivered from my server. The OpenLayers part is working fine for me too, EXCEPT I can't see the second layer--only the first is showing up.

Comment: I have had a look into it again and prepared another example using axios library request as well: https://jsfiddle.net/54fc05t1/ One possible error could also be the projection of your data, you can then either convert your received geometries, or change the views default projection to the desired format.